# Error "Project is subscribed by other projects" when deleting Gerrit project

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to delete one Gerrit project which is causing some problems. When I click on the "Delete" button I get this error.

```
Gerrit Code review error: 
Project is subscribed by other projects.
```

I looked at the `project.config` but could not find any reference to subscribers. Where can I find information about subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively, Gerrit does't have a "delete project" feature. Are you using some plugin? Assuming you're using the [delete-project](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/admin/projects/plugins/delete-project) plugin, you can't delete projects that use “submodule subscription”. You need to remove the submodule registration before attempting to delete the project. See more info [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/delete-project/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/about.md).

See [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-submodules.html) how to remove a submodule subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I am using the `delete plugin` but how can I remove the submodule registration?

Comment: I updated the answer with a link with all info about this.